# copy from managed class to native struct

Tags: c#, visual-c++, c++-cli

I need to fill native structs from managed classes. Following technique (1. copy managed data into managed byte array, 2. use memcopy to fill native struct) I found to be a common solution for this.
I assume the reason why following code doesn't work is that I use managed classes not managed structs. Having managed classes is a requirement in my project. Can I make this code work using managed classes, or must I switch to managed structs  ?

this is the c# managed class:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class man_s
    {
    public man_s()
    {
        // (do something which i can't do in a struct!)
    }

    // should go into a one-byte native bool
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
    public bool flag1;

    public Int32 a;

    public Int32 b;
    };
```

... the native cpp struct:

```
struct nat_s
    {
    public:
            bool flag1;
            __int32 a;
            __int32 b;
    };
```

... the code which should copy the managed data into the native struct:

```
// setup some managed data
man_s^ mng = man_s();
    mng->flag1 = true;
    mng->a = 10;
    mng->b = 20;

    nat_s nat;
    int s = sizeof(nat);

    // size check is ok!
    System::Diagnostics::Debug::Assert(sizeof(nat) == System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::SizeOf(mng));

    // copy into managed byte array
    array<byte>^ byteArray = gcnew array<byte>(s);
    System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::Copy(IntPtr((void*)(&mng)), byteArray, 0, s);

    // this doesn't bring up the expected results
    pin_ptr<byte> start = &byteArray[0];
    memcpy(&nat, start, s);

    // does not work either
    System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::Copy(byteArray, 0, IntPtr((void*)(&nat)), s);enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Marshal.Copy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy(v=vs.110).aspx) is for copying data between managed arrays and unmanaged arrays. That's not what you have here: You have a managed object, and an unmnaged struct. For that, you want the [`PtrToStructure`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostructure(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`StructureToPtr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.structuretoptr(v=vs.110).aspx) methods. Those methods target copying between a managed object and unmanaged memory of some sort.

```
// Despite the name, man_s is a managed class, not a managed struct. 
// This means it gets the ^ (which you had correct), 
// but it also means it gets gcnew (which you were missing).
man_s^ mng = gcnew man_s();
nat_s nat;

// You had this code is correct.
Debug::Assert(sizeof(nat) == Marshal::SizeOf(mng));

// StructureToPtr copies to unmanaged memory. 
// An unmanaged array (i.e., allocated with `malloc` or `new byte[]`)
// would work, but a pointer to the unmanaged struct will also work just fine.
// The `false` means "Don't destroy the object that's already at the destination", 
// which I believe does not apply here.
Marshal::StructureToPtr(mng, &nat, false);

// You can go the other way as well.
Marshal::PtrToStructure(&nat, mng);
// or
man_s = Marshal::PtrToStructure<man_s>(&nat);
```

<sub>Note: I'm not at a compiler right now. You might need to cast `&nat` to an `IntPtr`.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

No. AFAIK you can't do that. You know nothing about the memory layout of a managed `ref class`. You may allocate an inner `value type` inside the class. You may pin this and copy this as a whole block.

Also I don't understand your code. You copy a managed memory with Marshal::Copy. And you do this in converting a managed class to a native pointer. Than you copy this into managed memory and copy this managed memory again to a native memory! Why at all? If you have a pin pointer that works as a native pointer.

Comment: As said above, to copy managed to native, I learned it like: first, copy into managed byte array, and then do the bytewise memcpy into the native struct. That's all. Maybe a step too much. I'll give it a try with one step less using a value type. Thanks anyway!

Comment: ah, the last Marshal::Copy in the code commented "does not work either" is just a 2nd try which know I know must also fail.

Comment: ..tested it, you need 2 steps since the pin_ptr requires a standard type (byte) to establish a memcpy..